# Foxpro complex sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, foxpro

I'm having a hard time doing a query in foxpro 2.6 (no other choice)

note from some reason union queries do not work.

```
stockw (item, qte, dat) item is key
shist (item, qte, date) each row is a purchase for item and qte and date
```

the below query will calculate the first purchase for an item in shist to know how many months we've been selling every item since the beginning of the year

```
select shist.item as s_item, MIN(shist.date),stockw.qte as qte_remain,;
 IIF( YEAR(MIN(shist.date)) < 2013, MONTH(DATE()), MONTH(DATE())-MONTH(shist.date)+1 ) as months;
 FROM shist,stockw;
 WHERE (shist.item LIKE 'LF-TK%' OR shist.item LIKE 'PL%' OR shist.item LIKE 'LF-A%') AND stockw.item = shist.item;
 GROUP BY shist.item;
 into CURSOR x
```

i want to:
- calculate the average qte from the beginning of the year 2013 till now for each item SUM(shist.qte)/months (months is calculated from the above query for each item)

maybe in a different query i want the below:
- select the max of sum of shist.qte for every month for each item (get highest month) from the beginning of the year 2013 till now.

Comment: UNION doesn't work simply because it wasn't supported until Visual FoxPro 3.0

Comment: Not so. Just double-checked and UNION was in FoxPro 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not quite following where you would be applying a union, and appears you have multiple times you are running the query, here is a VERY OLD trick that was usable in the old days of VFP...

When you do a select into cursor, the cursor is typically read-only and not read-write to append to... BUT, if you use the result of the first time run query AGAIN as a different alias, you CAN append to it.  Something along the lines of...

```
use in select( "C_ThisIsMaster" )

for i = 1 to 10
   use in select( "C_ThisRun" )
   select blah, blah2, blah3 ;
      from YourTables;
      where SomeKey = SomeIDForCyclei;
      into cursor C_ThisRun

   if not used( "C_ThisIsMaster" )
      select 0
      use ( dbf( "C_ThisRun") ) again alias C_ThisIsMaster 
   else 
      select C_ThisIsMaster
      append from dbf( "C_ThisRun" )
   endif 
endfor
```

The for[i] loop is just a sample, but if you are running for many cycles that you would do the UNION for, you can just pull that into a query and simulate the same, such as via

```
select * 
   from SomeTable 
   where SomeCondition 
   into cursor C_DoTheseItems

use in select( "C_ThisIsMaster" )

select C_DoTheseItems
do while not eof()
   Do the same thing as inside the FOR loop above 

   select C_DoTheseItems
   skip 
enddo
```

I know VFP has scan/endscan, but don't remember how far back that originated, so using the do while NOT eof() was used here...

At the end of either option would give you a simulated UNION of each item you were trying to process into one "alias" result "C_ThisIsMaster" to work with

Comment: i ended up creating multiple queries, but since i don't know how to use the output as a table to run new query, i created a temporary table, run the new query on this table, then remove it

Comment: SCAN/ENDSCAN goes back to FoxPro 2.0.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor, I thought so, but didn't want to throw them off on what otherwise would still help